# Socket.io Best coding practice

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm developing a Node.js application which uses Socket.io to handle the real time communication. My code is full of On and Emit functions. I use room feature as well. my app looks like this:

```
   var server = require('http').Server();
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
      socket.on('event1', function(data){"lots of socket and non-socket codes" });
      socket.on('event2', function(data){"lots of socket and non-socket codes" });
      socket.on('event3', function(data){"lots of socket and non-socket codes" });
      socket.on('disconnect', function(){"Some other code"});
    });
    server.listen(portNum);
```

it works fine but It is not my ideal solution. 
Firstly, in this approach everything is in one big file instead of smaller file with isolated functionality.

secondly, it is quite difficult to debug and maintain this app as it is quite messy when it comes to 1000+ lines of code.

Here is my question:

Is there a preferred/best practice on developing enterprise quality Socke.io applications?
If yes, Is there any large opensource Socket.io application that demonstrait this approch or any article which help me to refactor my code in a better fassion?

Comment: I think starting by putting every callback function in a different function that you put out of io.on('connection'), and maybe also put them in a different file (using module.exports), you will start having a clearer application.

Comment: @Jujuleder that's exactly what I need. But I would like to know how this can be achieved while maintaining the socket object in all modules.

Answer (score 15):

I think starting by putting every callback function in a different function that you put out of io.on('connection'), and maybe also put them in a different file (using module.exports), you will start having a clearer application.

Ok so i will write you one possibility that i use, i don't know if it's the best pattern of the universe for socket.io, but that's good i think.

In your main file (the file with io.onconnection), you can have something like this (you dont have to use namespace, it's just an example) :

```
var SocketEvent = require('./socketEvent');

io.of('/user').on('connection', function (socket) {

    SocketEvent.load_common_event(socket);
    SocketEvent.load_user_event(socket);

});

io.of('/operator').on('connection', function (socket) {

    SocketEvent.load_common_event(socket);
    SocketEvent.load_operator_event(socket);

});
```

And in the socketEvent.js that you load you can have this :

```
exports.load_common_event = function(socket){
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){"Some other code"});
};

exports.load_user_event = function(socket){
    socket.on('event1', function(data){"lots of socket and non-socket codes" });
    socket.on('event2', function(data){"lots of socket and non-socket codes" });
    socket.on('event3', function(data){"lots of socket and non-socket codes" });
};

exports.load_operator_event = function(socket){
    socket.on('event4', function(data){"lots of socket and non-socket codes" });
    socket.on('event5', function(data){"lots of socket and non-socket codes" });
    socket.on('event6', function(data){"lots of socket and non-socket codes" });
};
```

Let me know if you have any question

**Add-on**

If you want something like Socket.on('event' , myModule.doSomething);

you can do like this i guess in the module :

client :

```
var myModule = require('./socketModule');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('event' , myModule.doSomething(/*some parameters (socket)*/));

});
```

server socketModule.js :

```
exports.doSomething = function(/*some parameters (socket)*/){
    /* Some processing around */
};
```

Comment: Thanks,  Although I don't use multiple Socket End points, the above approach is quite interesting.

Comment: I would be more interested in having something like 
`Socket.on('event' , myModule.doSomething);`
I'm not sure how myModule should be written.

Comment: In my myModule.doSomthing function, I have difficulty to access the socket object (e.g. to emit) along with the data comes from the client. for example, my client says socket.emit('event ', param1, param2); then Server listen to socket.on(event, function(param1, param2){/* some codes*/}). How can I reactor it to a function with both parameter and socket. E.g. doSomthing : fucntion (socket , param1 ,  param2){/* some codes*/}. @Jujuleder

Answer (score 1):

For those who are wondering about pass paremeters, `.bind` could be an option

```
const events = require('./events.js')
io.of('/chat').on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('print', events.print.bind({socket, io}))
})
```

event.js

```
const util = require('util')
function print(data) {
  console.log(util.inspect(this.socket).substr(0, 100))
  console.log(util.inspect(this.io).substr(0, 100))
}
module.exports = {
  print
}
```

Comment: what are you binding to? there is no function won't this be undefined?

Comment: @JeremyNelson `events.print` is a function and his `this` object is going to have `socket` and `io`, so inside this print function I have: `this.socket` and `this.io`. See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind and another thing, `socket.on` call the function after the event is fired, if I do `events.print()` print is going to be called imediately and so we have `undefined` in this case.

Answer (score -1):

More use of pages, less code in each, share them independently when needed:
**Note** I assume you are working with express. If not, just remove express from my demos.

```
// app.js
var app = require('express')();

module.exports = app;

// server.js
var app = require('./app');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

module.exports = server;

//socket-io-redis.js

var server      = require('../server');
var io          = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis       = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
io.set('origins', '*:*');

module.exports = io;
```

Now on every page on your API or on your server you can just import the Io instance (reference and efficient) like this:

```
var Io = require('../path/to/io-config-file');
console.log(Io); // object
Io.to(room).emit(event, payroll);
```

You can also make a main connection file like this:
**Note** I'm pasting here the exact code that I actually use, just in order to show you some of my best practices (of course, adapt and adjust this as your needs):

```
var { Io } = require('@dependencies/_index');
var Defaults = require('@helpers/defaults');
var _index = require('./services/_index');

const {
  validate,
  get_user,
  subscribe
} = _index;

Io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.on("join", async info => {
    await validate(info);
    await subscribe(await get_user(info), info, socket, 'join');
  });
  socket.on("leave", async info => {
    await validate(info);
    await subscribe(await get_user(info), info, socket, 'leave');
  });
});
```

In the example above, I listen for new connections and **securely verified** subscribe them to the respective rooms. I am using *services* in order to so - they are independent as I said that's how all your code should be like.