# What is best practice for separating socket.io related code in NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new to NodeJS. So I am writing NodeJS application with socket.io.

I understand how to separate controllers. In my app I created:
`controllers/userCtrl.js` 
`controller/marketCtrl.js` etc. 
And in `userCtrl.js` controller I did like this:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    // Create user
}

// Other actions
```

In application I use it:

```
// ...
var userCtrl = require('./controllers/userCtrl');
app.post('/user', userCtrl.create);
// ...
```

With models the same. But I have a lot of socket.io related code in `app.js` and don't understand how remove it (like controllers) from `app.js`:

```
var frontend = io.of('/frontend');
frontend.on('connection', function (client) {
logger.info('Someone connected to frontend socket');
client.on('join', function (message) {
    logger.info('In join event');
    var token = message.token;
    if (!token) {
        logger.debug('No usertoken provided. Sending login required');
        client.emit('join', {error: 103, message: 'Login required', data: null});
        return;
    }
//... etc..
```

My question is: How to split socket.io related code into files? What is best practice for it? Thank you!

Comment: Looks like same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153138/socket-io-best-coding-practice

Answer (score 1):

Different files is still the way. Use `exports` or `module.exports` and then just `require` in your `app.js`.

Perhaps make a `setup()` function that takes in an app/http instance, or whatever else you need in your socket.io stuff, and then call that function at the right time in app.js.

-- socketSetup.js --

```
'use strict';
var io = require('socket.io');
function setup( app, logger, whatever ){
  //do stuff here
}
module.exports = setup;
```

-- app.js --

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express');
var socketSetup = require('./socketSetup.js');

var app = express();
//other express things

//setup the socket stuff
socketSetup( app, logger );
```

The result is a shorter and more readable `app.js` file, and your socket setup is contained as well. Repeat as things grow in your `socketSetup.js` file as well.